# Endpoint to fetch Subreddits of a Reddit Account

Tags: node.js, reddit, reddit-access-token

I have completed the oauth flow for my third party app against a Reddit account and I've gotten the access token for the account.

Now my next issue is

> How can I fetch the subreddits for an account using the access token

I can't seem to figure out the endpoint for that.

Does anyone know the endpoint for that?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

The Reddit OAuth Docs say that for the [/subreddits/mine/(where)](https://www.reddit.com/dev/api#GET_subreddits_mine_%7Bwhere%7D) endpoint, the `subreddits` OAuth scope is necessary.

Once that scope is acquired for a user, you can use the following snippets of code to access the list of subscribed subreddits for the user:

| View a users subreddits | [<kbd>View in Fusebit</kbd>](https://api.us-west-1.on.fusebit.io/v1/run/sub-c2eaf0578e7140ca/share/share/edit?integrationId=so-70392539) |
| --- | --- |

```js
  // Demonstrate using snooclient and Fusebit
  const subscriptions = await redditClient.getSubscriptions().fetchAll();

  // OR fetch the first page using a raw HTTP request
  // - the User-Agent is necessary, don't forget it!
  const access_token = redditClient.fusebit.credentials.access_token;
  const httpSubs = await superagent.get(
    'https://oauth.reddit.com/subreddits/mine/subscriber')
    .set('Authorization', `Bearer ${access_token}`)
    .set('User-Agent', 'Fusebit Integration');

  const length = httpSubs.body.data.children.length;
  ctx.body = {
    usingSnoo: `User has ${subscriptions.length} subreddits`,
    usingHttp: `The first page has ${length} subreddits`,
  };
});
```